# Regular expression to select everything outside <> in a string

Tags: regex, string, select

I'm not very handy with regex and I need to select everything outside <> to get the length of the string, excluding the "<>".

For example: `first<second>third<fourth>fifth` should give me `first third fifth`.

How can I do it? I spent some hours searching the web but I didn't really find what I needed. The regex is needed for use in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can always replace the text between smaller than and greater than symbols using regex below.

`/<\w+>/g`

In this case the text which is outside remains.
See https://regexr.com/422jf

Comment: Tanks for the suggestion :)